# MaterialDesign ColorZone Height size

Tags: c#, wpf, material-design

I don't know why, but my ColorZone is changing the height by itself.
When I don't have `materialDesign:ColorZone`, the size of the grid with all my element has the size of `"*"`.

But when I add `ColorZone`, the size decrease... Do you know how to fix it ?

```
   <Grid Grid.Column="1" Visibility="Visible" >
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

        <materialDesign:ColorZone Padding="16" materialDesign:ShadowAssist.ShadowDepth="Depth2"
                                      Mode="PrimaryLight">
            <Grid>
               <!-- ALL MY ELEMENT, SIZE CHANGE COZ OF COLORZONE -->
            </Grid>
        </materialDesign:ColorZone>
    </Grid>
```

EDIT : This is the height, why this is not taking all the space ? It does only when I write the width in the ColorZone

[image]

Comment: Some screenshots would be helpful. What's size is decreasing, the whole thing? The rows in the grid? Do you only have one row in your grid?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I copied your code into my project. There's a couple of things I think could be causing your issue.

[image]

1. You've got padding in your color zone. If you didn't have the color zone, you wouldn't have 16 points of padding. This will cause the layout to have an extra 32 points of space in both directions it has to display, increasing the size. This is a size increase, not decrease though.
2. Note how the color zone doesn't stretch to fill it's contents, are you expecting this behavior? I'm not sure if it could be causing the size change you are expecting, but it might be a reason things don't look like what  you expect.

Without more information (what you want it to look like, exactly what the problem is) this is the best answer I can provide.

**Edit:** Thanks for the screenshot, that clarifies things perfectly.

The default ColorZone alignment is top left. I don't know why, because in almost every case I've found I align it to stretch to fill all available space like most other WPF containers (Grid, stack panel etc).

You need to add the following:

```
HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch"
```

to your colorzone. Alternatively, in your App.xaml resources, you could make a generic Style for ColorZone, and have these as the defaults. I really should get around to this with my application:

```
<Style TargetType="materialDesign:ColorZone">
    <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Stretch"/>
    <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment" Value="Stretch"/>
</Style>
```

Comment: I edited my problem. Yes, your point 2 is exactly what I'm looking for. I don't know why, but this is not filling the entire space

Comment: This is perfect ! Why the value Stretch is doing this ? I don't understand

Comment: The default is HorizontalAlignment="Left" which makes it scrunch up on the left, and VerticalAlignment="Top" which makes it scrunch up at the top. So it makes itself the smallest it can. These layout options can be used with anything (try setting them on the grid inside the colorzone, you'll get a similar behavior, but with just the content). Stretch tells it to fill all available space.